# netty 4 ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelReadComplete called twice

Tags: client, netty

when you use netty (4.0.23, java 1.7u67, win8x64) as a client [ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelReadComplete(...)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelReadComplete(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext)) should be called 1 time once netty completes reading response, right?

Trying different sites, it's always called twice:

```java
@Test
    public void testDoubleReadComplete() throws Exception {
        final String host = "www.google.de";
        final CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(20);
        bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                .group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                String request = String.format(
                                                "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" +
                                                "Host: " + host +"\n" +
                                                "\n\n"
                                );
                                System.out.println("sending...");
                                System.out.println(request);

                                ByteBuf req = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(request.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
                                ctx.writeAndFlush(req);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                System.err.println("777 read complete");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                ByteBuf resp = (ByteBuf) msg;

                                count.countDown();

                                System.out.printf("****************************************************>>>>> %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                System.out.println(resp.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
                                System.out.println("<<<<<****************************************************");

                                resp.release();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80));
        future.awaitUninterruptibly();

        count.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

outputs `777 read complete` 2 times, why?

Comment: found a reason, see answer comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972426/netty-4-channelinboundhandleradapter-channelreadcomplete-called-twice/25995926#comment40823007_25995926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the `channelReadComplete` is intended for how you are trying to use it.
Read the [javadoc](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.java#L56) for the method. The data is not guaranteed to arrive all at once and so netty reads the data as it arrives in a non-blocking manner.  This methods notifies you when it has finished `the current read operation` which is not necessarily the last read operation.

I'm not exactly sure about your use case but here is some non-production code that may be closer to what you are trying to accomplish?

```
@Test
public void testDoubleReadComplete() throws Exception {
    final String host = "www.google.de";
    final CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(20);
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                            String request = String.format(
                                            "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                                            "Host: " + host +"\r\n" +
                                            "Connection: close\r\n" +
                                            "\r\n"
                            );
                            System.out.println("sending...");
                            System.out.println(request);

                            ByteBuf req = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(request.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
                            ctx.writeAndFlush(req);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                            System.err.println("777 read complete");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                            ByteBuf resp = (ByteBuf) msg;

                            count.countDown();

                            System.out.printf("****************************************************>>>>> %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            System.out.println(resp.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
                            System.out.println("<<<<<****************************************************");

                            resp.release();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the difference between `read` & `readComplete` then?
`netty reads the data as it arrives in a non-blocking manner` - true, and it calls `read` in this case, it shouldn't call `readComplete` each time data appears in a socket, right?

Comment: `channelRead` is the actual data that was read.  This may be called multiple times depending on a number of environmental issues (how the OS is buffering data for the application, what type of channel you are using within Netty/java, etc...). `channelReadComplete` means that there is no more data currently available (Netty would have to block to wait for more data) and Netty is going to return back to the event loop to wait to be notified that more data is available to be read.

Comment: So to answer your question...there is nothing preventing `channelReadComplete` being called for each read if this is how data is delivered to netty.  It looks like you should be using a different mechanism to determine if the response is complete.  Look at the HTTP-codec which should provide this functionality for you.  See the [http examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http) to get started.

Comment: Scott, thanks, closely but not exactly: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/nio/AbstractNioByteChannel.java#L149 - so it's depends also on `ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ` which is 16 by default

Comment: btw, now I'm testing with `.option(ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` and so far so good - `channelReadComplete` is called once at the end of response as I need, am I missing smth...?

Comment: Good reference, and I'm glad you found this option.  However just setting this flag does not guarantee that `channelReadComplete` is  called only 1 time per logical application response.  See [this line](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/nio/AbstractNioByteChannel.java#L116) and imagine the data is coming to your machine in a delayed and chunked manner (poor network conditions, etc...).  If this is the case the `doReadBytes` could be called, return 0, and then the loop will break and `channelReadComplete` will be called.

Comment: At some later time when the rest of the data arrives you will re-enter this loop and repeat.  The MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ is just to ensure no 1 read operation hogs all the resources on a particular thread.  For example I get `channelReadCalled` more than 2 times and the amount of times is not necessarily consistent.  This may be because network conditions are worse between my machine and `google.de` and your machine and `google.de` (possibly because you are in country and I am not?).

Comment: I would recommend you reconsider marking your response as the answer to this question.  I believe it is misleading and is there a reason you are not using the HTTP-codec?  The HTTP-codec should take care of these types of issues for you and provide a nice level of abstraction. See the [http codec examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http) to get started.

Comment: Scott, thanks, I don't use http codec because I want to maximize performance (as http stress client) from single machine, but http codec have persistent logic and it's quite heavy and complex, so I'm trying to implement `end of logical response` by myself with fastest code as possible. So I'll analyze http codec logic further and try different netty options and hope will come to an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

found the cause and solution: `ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ`

So now I'm testing with `.option(ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` and so far so good - `channelReadComplete` is called once at the end of response as I need